# Subsetting data from table by station numbers to new files

Tags: r

I am having a challenge with the following task. I have precipitation data (daily accumulation) for 2008-2021 stored in monthly CSV files that contain station number (column 1), parameter code (column 2), date & time (column 3), and precipitation value (column 4).

My goal is to create a single CSV file for every station, which will contain all precipitation data from 2008-2021, and the code of the station will be in the file name.

In the original files, I have more than 500 stations to subset. Please find below an exemplary subset of the data I am struggling with (just three different stations and data for one month).

```
structure(list(V1 = c(250180590L, 250180590L, 250180590L, 250180590L, 250180590L, 250160530L, 250160530L, 250160530L, 250160530L, 250160530L,  250160630L, 250160630L, 250160630L, 250160630L, 250160630L), 
V2 = c("B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", 
"B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", 
"B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S", "B00604S"), V3 = c("2008-01-01 06:00", 
"2008-01-02 06:00", "2008-01-03 06:00", "2008-01-04 06:00", 
"2008-01-05 06:00", "2008-01-01 06:00", "2008-01-02 06:00", 
"2008-01-03 06:00", "2008-01-04 06:00", "2008-01-05 06:00", 
"2008-01-01 06:00", "2008-01-02 06:00", "2008-01-03 06:00", 
"2008-01-04 06:00", "2008-01-05 06:00"), V4 = c(5, 2.8, 0, 
0, 0, 0.9, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 1.6, 0, 0), V5 = c(",", 
"", ",", ",", ",", "", "", ",", ",", ",", "", ",", "", ",", 
",")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try this:
  
`for (i in unique(df$V1)) {
  write.csv(df[df$V1==i,], file = paste0(i,".csv"), row.names = F)
}`

Comment: It works! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so, so much for the quick help!